# Upgrading leaf machine in Memsql

Tags: singlestore

My leaf are currently running on ec2 30 GB ram machines, can I upgrade the same machines to 60 GB ram machines and ensure that memsql leaf memory increases accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can.

If you are adding more memory to the same machines, you just need to

- Stop memsql: `memsql-ops memsql-stop`
- Provision the new RAM on the machine
- Start memsql: `memsql-ops memsql-start`
- Configure the new memory limit: `memsql-ops memsql-update-config --set-global --key maximum_memory --value value_in_mb` - see https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002247706-How-do-I-change-MemSQL-s-memory-limits-after-changing-system-memory-capacity-

If you are switching to new machines instead of provisioning more memory on the same machines, then you can:

- Deploy the new machines, install MemSQL on them, and add them to your cluster: https://docs.memsql.com/quickstarts/v5.8/quick-start-on-premises/#5-add-more-host-machines-and-memsql-nodes
- Run `memsql-ops cluster-manual-control --enable`
- Run `REMOVE LEAF 'host':port` for all the old machines that you now want to remove. This will move the data to the new nodes.
- Run `memsql-ops memsql-delete` on each of the old leaf nodes that you just ran `REMOVE LEAF` on. This will delete the nodes which are now empty of data after the last step.
- Run `memsql-ops cluster-manual-control --disable`